# Matplotlib fill between plot and horizontal line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

sorry but i can't post my real data or plot.. so I made pictoral plot in MS paint.

So I have my plot - orange line, given as set of X and Y values `plt.plot(data_x, data_y)`.
Then I added horizontal line - blue line that way: `plt.axvline(x=10)`.
Now I would like to fill with color space between this line and my plot (ultimately, with one color when values are belowe horizontal line, and second when they are above).

I tried with `plt.fill` and `plt.fill_between` and `plt.axhspan` though, i receive errors either with dimensionality issues or elements vs sequence.

Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a `where` parameter of [`ax.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) for doing this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# make data
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, 300)
y = np.sin(x)

# init figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot sin and line
ax.plot(x, y, color='orange')
ax.axhline(0)

# fill between hline and y, but use (y > 0) and (y < 0)
# to create boolean masks determining where to fill
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=(y > 0), color='orange', alpha=.3)
ax.fill_between(x, y, where=(y < 0), color='blue', alpha=.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
data_y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
data_y2 = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.fill_between(data_x, data_y, data_y2,
                where=data_y2 >= data_y,
                facecolor='green', interpolate=True)
ax.fill_between(data_x, data_y, data_y2,
                where=data_y2 <= data_y,
                facecolor='red', interpolate=True)
```

Note that data_y2 has to be a scalar (e.g. 0) or of the same shape as data_y.

Here you will find the relevant docu:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html

and

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html